# Difference between PHP DateTime and date method

Tags: php, datetime

I show one statement in http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php which says in Example #1 DateTime::format() example that "This method does not use ***locales***. All output is in English". 
Also mentioned there that "date() - Format a ***local*** time/date". I tested them with:

```
<?php
//test1
$date = new DateTime('2013-11-09 01:08:32');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//test2
$d = strtotime('2013-11-09 01:08:32');
echo "<br/>".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$d);
?>
```

Both show the same output. I want to know the significance of the word "local" with this context. Please could anyone explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is between *locale* and *local time*. They don't mean the same thing at all.

*locale* indicates the translation. As it says, it doesn't translate the date string; it outputs in English.

*local time* indicates the time according to the server's timezone setting. If you're using UCT for your time zone then this won't be relevant, but if you've set the time zone to a local time then it will make a big difference.

Answer (score 4):

In `date()`'s case, "local" refers to the time zone, and is in contrast to GMT/UTC (thus, the existence of `gmdate()`).

Both functions output English language dates by default. Per the `date()` docs:

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date().